# Inserção de itens em um ArrayList não funciona como esperado

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Preciso que seja adicionado um item na lista 9 vezes, só que, quando imprimo, só aparece o dado `12 , "Oi", "Aline"`. O que estou fazendo de errado?

package webservice;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
public class LivroResource{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 10;
    List<Livro> livros = null;
    Livro livro;
    while(i != 0){

        livros = new ArrayList<>();
        livro = new Livro();

        livro.setId(12);
        livro.setTitulo("Oi");
        livro.setAutor("Aline");
        livros.add(livro);
        i--;
        System.out.println(i);

    }

    for(Livro biblioteca : livros){

    System.out.println(biblioteca.getId());
    System.out.println(biblioteca.getAutor());
    System.out.println(biblioteca.getTitulo());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remova esta linha do laço, cada iteração, você está criando uma nova lista e apagando a anterior:

```
  livros = new ArrayList<>();
```

Deixe assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 10;
    List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
    Livro livro;
    while(i != 0){

        livro = new Livro();

        livro.setId(12);
        livro.setTitulo("Oi");
        livro.setAutor("Aline");
        livros.add(livro);
        i--;
        System.out.println(i);

    }

    for(Livro biblioteca : livros){

    System.out.println(biblioteca.getId());
    System.out.println(biblioteca.getAutor());
    System.out.println(biblioteca.getTitulo());
    }
  }
}
```

Creio que a condição do laço, apesar de funcionar, não seja a mais adequada pra situação, uma vez que você quer preencher 10 posições de forma decrescente. `while(i > 0)` tem o mesmo efeito e torna o código mais compreensivel.

Comment: Deu certo! muito obrigada.